# jQuery: how to select all elements that are pseudo-elements having :before or :after?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

in jQuery or basic javascript is posible to get all elements with :after or :before pseudo-element?

I know getcomputedstyle, but this return all elements with or without :before or :after pseudo-element.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Something like:

```
$("a:before").each(function () {
  console.log("element with :before pseudo-element")
});
```

Comment: What would it mean for an element to have, say, an ":after" pseudo-class?  Are you looking for those elements to which the style engine has attached some ":after" content?  I doubt that list is available to the script engine.

Comment: Those are pseudo-elements, not pseudo-classes.

Comment: I want to work only with elements that has :before pseudo-element in the css

Comment: Could you explain or give a bit more context around what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: ok! i have five <a> without :before style, and three <a> with :before style. With jQuery, I will get only the <a> with :before style? You know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Generated content elements are not really part of the DOM. You can't directly hook into them using JS. They are for presentation only.

You can do things to actual elements that may be parents or siblings etc. of the pseudo-elements and change them that way.

Looking at the question BoltClock linked to below, maybe you could set a common attribute to all pseudo-elements and then try and select them with jquery based on this attribute.

Comment: @refhat: [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery) (This seems like a different question, though...)

Answer (score 0):

Give the 'a' tags you want to select a class such as 'has-before' and hook on to them that way?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but in a round-about way!

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BE47z/1/

The logic goes like:

1. Enumerate all classes that have a `:before` or an `:after` definition in CSS - this is done by traversing the `document.styleSheets` object (*you can change the code to only catch `:before` or `:after` etc.. as needed*)
2. Once you get the class list, remove the part after : its name in CSS, for ex: `.a:before` becomes `.a`
3. Now you can get all elements matching those classes

**Code**

**HTML**

```
<div class="element classWithoutBefore">No :before</div>
<div class="element classWithBefore">Has :before</div>
<div class="element class2WithBefore">Has :before</div>
<div class="element class2WithoutBefore">No :before</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.classWithoutBefore {

}

.class2WithoutBefore {

}

.classWithBefore:before {

}

.class2WithBefore:before {

}

.a:before, .b:before {

}
```

**JS**

```
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
var pseudoClasses = [], i = 0, j = 0;
for (i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    try {
        var rules = sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (j=0; j<rules.length; j++) {
            if(rules[j].selectorText.indexOf(':before') != -1 || rules[j].selectorText.indexOf(':after') != -1) {
                pseudoClasses.push(rules[j].selectorText);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(ex) { // will throw security exception for style sheets loaded from external domains
    }
}

var classes = [];
if(pseudoClasses.length > 0) {
    pseudoClasses = pseudoClasses.join(',').split(','); // quick & dirty way to seperate individual class names
    for (i=0; i<pseudoClasses.length; i++) { // remove all class names without a : in it
        var colonPos = pseudoClasses[i].indexOf(':');
        if(colonPos != -1) {
            classes.push(pseudoClasses[i].substring(0, colonPos));
        }
    }
}

// Elements with the classes in the 'classes' array have a :before or :after defined
```

Comment: `:hover` is a pseudo-class and not the same kind of selector as `:before` or `:after` which are pseudo-elements. There's no such thing as a "pseudo". **Please don't get them mixed up.**

Comment: Yes. The script is for blindly picking up anything with a : in the css definition and using that to match the elements. So called it just `pseudo` generically (which is a wrong way).. But yes, they are totally unrelated i know. The script above should be edited (especially the indexOf part where the matching is done) by the OP to suit his needs as i pointed out.. :)